# Weil pairing as an algebraic cycle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Is there an algebraic cycle corresponding to the Weil pairing on an abelian variety (of dim>1)? Ideally I'd like to see an example as explicit as possible, e.g. 
an explicitly given variety of dim>1 and an explicitly given subvariety.

Comment: Do you mean the Poincare pairing between the cohomology of an abelian variety and its dual, or the pairing on the cohomology of an abelian variety induced by the choice of a polarization? I would think the latter is just the polarization pairing attached to the ample line bundle that's giving you the polarization (at least up to sign). 

Comment: OP: Can you say more precisely what you are looking for?  The Weil pairing is usually thought of as a pairing only on $n$-torsion points taking values in the group of $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity.  In what sense would you like to see this as an algebraic cycle?  Are you asking how to interpret this as a pairing of the corresponding torsion invertible sheaves (on the respective dual Abelian varieties)?  For that, see Deligne's expose in SGA 4.